# Kill python background process gitlab-ci

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I'm trying to kill a python job started in background in an Alpine docker in a gitlab-ci:

**Python**

```
import asyncio

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Stopping')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are the commands that are ran.

```
$ COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage.test coverage run test.py &
$ TEST_PID=$!
$ echo "${TEST_PID}"
26
$ kill -SIGINT ${TEST_PID}
$ jobs -l
[1]+  26 Running                 
$ kill -9 ${TEST_PID}
$ jobs -l
[1]+  26 Running
```

I can never see the `.coverage.test` as the job never finishes.
However it seems to work fine when I run the commands locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a SIGINT to Python from a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974189/how-to-send-a-sigint-to-python-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: I saw and tried the above; it did not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution:
 - First, add `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, quit_gracefully)` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974189/how-to-send-a-sigint-to-python-from-a-bash-script).
 - Then add the `wait` command after the kill:

```
COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage.test coverage run test.py &
TEST_PID=$!
kill -SIGINT ${TEST_PID}
wait
```